# Add a warning if a method is not called in a specific class

Tags: android, android-studio

So, what I'd like to achieve is:
I have a custom class which is basically a HttpRequest, I create the object with url, parameters, etc. And then I have to call **execute()** to execute it.

I was wondering, is there a way - by annotations, or whatever - to make Android Studio remind me to call this method?

I remember the was something similar with the android Toast, in the IDE a message like **'Did you forget to call show?'** was shown if, in fact, I forgot to call show() after creating the Toast.

Thanks much to anyone who will help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create

1. [Create a custom IntelliJ inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-custom-inspections.html)
2. [A custom LINT rule](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules), if you want to check it on your build server and not on your local machine.

Comment: according to this post it is not possible to do this with lint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225927/how-does-android-studio-know-to-display-the-toast-created-but-not-shown-did-yo