# How does Android Studio know to display the "Toast created but not shown: did you forget to call show()?" warning?

Tags: android, android-studio

When you create a Toast but do not call the `show()` method Android Studio shows an tooltip saying: "Toast created but not shown: did you forget to call show()?" another example is not calling `commit` or `apply` when putting values into a `SharedPreferencesEditor` object and a tooltip being displayed.

Is this just Android Studio being helpful or is there a way to define that after a method is called another method should be called?

Comment: AFAIK it's done with lint using static code analysis

Comment: I saw a YouTube video about an Android Studio release recently that mentioned this feature was added, but I probably won't be able to find it.

Comment: Actually, found it - Roughly starting at 25:00  https://youtu.be/Erd2k6EKxCQ?t=1497

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the video! Confirms that it is Lint.

Comment: Yeah - I didn't realize how old that video was. Feature was carried over from Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just Intellij (Android Studio) being smart enough to figure through static code analysis.

There is no way to tell the compiler that after such method another method should run. The closest thing to it is writing *unit tests* and even that only notifies you during your test runs.